# How to smooth transition between elements of different heights in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am building a Bootstrap carousel for a project. The content of the slides have different heights. Currently, the transition animation for the different sized content is very choppy. I am wondering if there is any way to fix this transition and make it a bit more graceful/smooth as the carousel adjusts in height between the slides.

*Please note that I would like to maintain the different heights between the slides. They are sized that way for a reason that is essential to the project.

[Please see an example of the choppy transition on JS Bin.](https://jsbin.com/vekeguxezi/edit?html,output)

Here is the code for the carousel:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Bootstrap Carousel</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="http://placehold.it/160x600">
    </div>
  </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add style .item img{ height:300px !important; width:auto;}

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to maintain the differences in height. I do not want the content to be scaled down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was chopping a lot because of the translation left/right so if u remove it it should be a lot better.

```
.carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: none;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important;
}

.carousel-inner .active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

but if u meant animate the height between different image sizes than u can use this jQuery:

```
$('.carousel').carousel().on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var nextH = $(e.relatedTarget).height();
    $(this).find('.active.item').parent().animate({
        height: nextH
    }, 1000);
});
```

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgWBpP)**

Comment: This cuts off the image content for me. I also do not want to scale down the content in the carousel. I'd like to maintain the differences in height. Just fix the transition to make it more smooth and less choppy.

Comment: Maintain the differences in height, not sure what u mean by that. The transitions is smooth, its not choppy at all.

Comment: The third slide, which is 160x600, is cut off. If I scaled this slide to fit within the 300px height, it would scale down and become smaller. I am not looking to scale the images to fit within a constrained height. I am hoping to maintain the elements varying heights and fix the choppy carousel animation that adjusts between these different heights. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LizBanach i changed my CODEPEN and the answer. I tried to avoid the translation left/right it helped a lot, not sure how else to improve it.

Comment: That looks great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can use javascript to done that.

[Example](https://jsbin.com/yoxaposequ/edit?js,output)

In that code I add event listener for listen `slide.bs.carousel` that triggered from bootstrap, get height of active item then animate `carousel-inner` element height.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="item active">
  <div class="img" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/300x300')"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="img" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/250x250')"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="img" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/160x600')"></div>
</div>
```

Add style

```
.item .img {
   height:600px; //Maximum height
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:center center;
}
```